# Error 1290 despite of fixing my.ini file and having FILE permissions

Tags: mysql

I tried loading data from a file but got ERROR 1290.

```
mysql> show variables like 'secure_file_priv';
+------------------+------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value                                          |
+------------------+------------------------------------------------+
| secure_file_priv | C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\ |
+------------------+------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> load data infile "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\Book1.csv"
into table sample fields terminated by ',';

ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option
so it cannot execute this statement
```

I've aready tried the below link but didn't help.

> > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34102562/mysql-error-1290-hy000-secure-file-priv-option

I also have `FILE` privilege for the current_user.

[image: my.ini file]

That's how Book1.csv looks

```
1,A,A1
2,B,A2
3,C,A3
4,A,A4
5,B,A5
6,C,A6
7,A,A7
8,B,A8
9,C,A9
10,A,A10
```

I've spent hours. Pls help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In windows, you need to give double slash "\" in the path.

```
   load data infile "C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\Book1.csv" into table sample fields terminated by ',';
```

You can give reverse slash "/" as below

```
   load data infile "C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/Book1.csv" into table sample fields terminated by ',';
```

Give it a try.

Answer (score -2):

Check your separator in file book and the delimitor (or separator ) set by default in MySQL.
you can upload through cmd with command :

```
LOAD DATA INFILE ‘path/to/filename.csv’ INTO TABLE TABLENAME FIELDS 
TERMINATED BY ‘,’ LINES TERMINATED BY ‘\n’ 
IGNORE 1 LINES; -- If you have line to ignore ;
```

Comment: I've updated the question. N your answer should rather be a comment.